# backbone.js cannot fetch a single model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having a problem fetching a model that is outside of a collection.  I have seen many solutions and for some reason none seem to be working (probably doing something stupid).  I have a success function in my actual fetch which never fires.  It should be hitting /devices/{deviceId}

Here is my code

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',


], function(_, Backbone) {
  // Creating backbone model
  var DeviceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // set defaults
    defaults: {
    },

    idAttribute: "deviceId",
    urlRoot: '/devices'
  })
  return DeviceModel;
});
```

and I am calling it from

```
        model = new DeviceModel({deviceId: this.deviceId })

        model.fetch()
```

Thank you!

Comment: after model.fetch() did you see get query in browser "network"?

Comment: does your server provide a model at `youserver.com/devices/deviceId` ?

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich no I don't

Comment: @pfried I don't have access to the server, I am using backmock to fake the data coming back.  Nothing shows up in the network tab of chrome though :/

Comment: Incidentally if I make the url: '/devices/1' it works fine (note NOT urlRoot)

Comment: Also I was able to put this
`this.__proto__.url = '/devices/' + this.get('deviceId')`
in the initialization and it returns the model now.... as it doesn't look like I should need this is this perhaps a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: can you check if the id attribute is set correctly? just log `model.id`

Comment: check error by using like the code : like `error: function(model, xhr, options)` // `xhr` - shows all things  You need

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass callback functions to debug what is going on with:

```
  model.fetch()
```

From the documentation of [BackboneJS Model-Fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)

> Accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which are
>   both passed (model, response, options) as arguments.

So, you can include:

```
model.fetch({success: function(m, resp) { console.log(resp);}, 
               error: function(m, resp) { console.log(resp);} 
            });
```